# Is any way can let Cloud Dataflow output like stream?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I use Google Cloud Dataflow to process bound data and output to BigQuery, and I want it can process something and write something (like stream, not batch), Is any way I can do this?

Currently, Dataflow will wait worker process dont all data, and write to BigQuery, I try to add FixedWindow and use Log Timestamp param be a window_timestamp, but It doesn't work.

I want to know:

1. Is windowing right way to handle this problem?
2. Is BigQueryIO really write batch or maybe it just not show on my dashboard (background write stream?)
3. Is any way to do I need?

My source code is here: http://pastie.org/10907947

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `streaming` property to `true` in your `PipelineOptions`.

See ["streaming execution"](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#streaming-execution) for more information.

In addition, you'll need to be using sources/sinks that can generate/consume unbounded data. BigQuery can already write in both modes, but currently TextIO only reads bounded data. But it's definitely possible to write a custom unbounded source that scans a directory for new files.